# I can't properly include one result from CTE into query, and can't figure out how to do it

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I created a query to retrieve a sum of sold goods for certain departments in a certain year, the sum for all of the departments for a certain country and year, and the percent of a sum from department to sum for a country. I need to count the difference between percentage for the previous year and current year (1998 for 1999,1999 for 2000 etc.). Tables:

```
Americas    1999    Direct Sales    7932550.86  12464862.43 63.64%
Americas    1999    Internet    1377051.66  12464862.43 11.05%
Americas    1999    Partners    3155259.91  12464862.43 25.31%
    Asia    1999    Direct Sales    1369875.55  2395268.48  57.19%
    Asia    1999    Internet    285153.52   2395268.48  11.90%
    Asia    1999    Partners    740239.41   2395268.48  30.90%
    Europe  1999    Direct Sales    4755014.09  6502887.40  73.12%
    Europe  1999    Internet    511273.40   6502887.40  7.86%
    Europe  1999    Partners    1236599.91  6502887.40  19.02%
Americas    2000    Direct Sales    7967141.89  13788324.32 57.78%
Americas    2000    Internet    1162343.86  13788324.32 8.43%
Americas    2000    Partners    4658838.57  13788324.32 33.79%
    Asia    2000    Direct Sales    1242257.78  2343114.67  53.02%
    Asia    2000    Internet    242492.77   2343114.67  10.35%
    Asia    2000    Partners    858364.12   2343114.67  36.63%
    Europe  2000    Direct Sales    4493735.78  6737500.98  66.70%
    Europe  2000    Internet    415135.09   6737500.98  6.16%
    Europe  2000    Partners    1828630.11  6737500.98  27.14%
```

this table consists of information about the years from 1999 to 2000.

And the second one for previous years:

```
Americas    1998    Direct Sales    8340188.74  13468418.60 61.92%
Americas    1998    Internet    1714392.70  13468418.60 12.73%
Americas    1998    Partners    3155712.64  13468418.60 23.43%
Americas    1998    Tele Sales  258124.52   13468418.60 1.92%
    Asia    1998    Direct Sales    1409654.80  2468506.67  57.11%
    Asia    1998    Internet    320522.72   2468506.67  12.98%
    Asia    1998    Partners    734810.33   2468506.67  29.77%
    Asia    1998    Tele Sales  3518.82         2468506.67  .14%
    Europe  1998    Direct Sales    5101419.96  7102517.23  71.83%
    Europe  1998    Internet    686048.60   7102517.23  9.66%
    Europe  1998    Partners    1301521.63  7102517.23  18.32%
    Europe  1998    Tele Sales  13527.04    7102517.23  .19%
Americas    1999    Direct Sales    7932550.86  12464862.43 63.64%
Americas    1999    Internet    1377051.66  12464862.43 11.05%
Americas    1999    Partners    3155259.91  12464862.43 25.31%
    Asia    1999    Direct Sales    1369875.55  2395268.48  57.19%
    Asia    1999    Internet    285153.52   2395268.48  11.90%
    Asia    1999    Partners    740239.41   2395268.48  30.90%
    Europe  1999    Direct Sales    4755014.09  6502887.40  73.12%
    Europe  1999    Internet    511273.40   6502887.40  7.86%
    Europe  1999    Partners    1236599.91  6502887.40  19.02%
```

My desired output was:

```
Americas    1999    Direct Sales    7932550.86  12464862.43 63.64%    61.92%
Americas    1999    Internet    1377051.66  12464862.43 11.05%    12.73%
Americas    1999    Partners    3155259.91  12464862.43 25.31%    23.43%
    Asia    1999    Direct Sales    1369875.55  2395268.48  57.19%    57.11%
    Asia    1999    Internet    285153.52   2395268.48  11.90%    12.98%
    Asia    1999    Partners    740239.41   2395268.48  30.90%    29.77%
    Europe  1999    Direct Sales    4755014.09  6502887.40  73.12%    71.83%
    Europe  1999    Internet    511273.40   6502887.40  7.86%     9.66%
    Europe  1999    Partners    1236599.91  6502887.40  19.02%    18.32%
Americas    2000    Direct Sales    7967141.89  13788324.32 57.78%    63.64%
Americas    2000    Internet    1162343.86  13788324.32 8.43%     11.05%
Americas    2000    Partners    4658838.57  13788324.32 33.79%    25.31%
    Asia    2000    Direct Sales    1242257.78  2343114.67  53.02%    57.19%
    Asia    2000    Internet    242492.77   2343114.67  10.35%    11.90%
    Asia    2000    Partners    858364.12   2343114.67  36.63%    30.90%
    Europe  2000    Direct Sales    4493735.78  6737500.98  66.70%    73.12%
    Europe  2000    Internet    415135.09   6737500.98  6.16%     7.86%
    Europe  2000    Partners    1828630.11  6737500.98  27.14%    19.02%
```

And difference on the end, meaning (val1 - val2).

But what I am receiving is:

```
Americas    1999    Direct Sales    23797652.58 37394587.29 63.64%  57.78%
Americas    1999    Direct Sales    23797652.58 37394587.29 63.64%  61.92%
Americas    1999    Direct Sales    23797652.58 37394587.29 63.64%  63.64%
Americas    1999    Internet    4131154.98  37394587.29 11.05%  11.05%
Americas    1999    Internet    4131154.98  37394587.29 11.05%  12.73%
Americas    1999    Internet    4131154.98  37394587.29 11.05%  8.43%
Americas    1999    Partners    9465779.73  37394587.29 25.31%  23.43%
Americas    1999    Partners    9465779.73  37394587.29 25.31%  25.31%
Americas    1999    Partners    9465779.73  37394587.29 25.31%  33.79%
    Asia    1999    Direct Sales    4109626.65  7185805.44  57.19%  53.02%
    Asia    1999    Direct Sales    4109626.65  7185805.44  57.19%  57.11%
    Asia    1999    Direct Sales    4109626.65  7185805.44  57.19%  57.19%
    Asia    1999    Internet    855460.56   7185805.44  11.90%  10.35%
    Asia    1999    Internet    855460.56   7185805.44  11.90%  11.90%
    Asia    1999    Internet    855460.56   7185805.44  11.90%  12.98%
    Asia    1999    Partners    2220718.23  7185805.44  30.90%  29.77%
    Asia    1999    Partners    2220718.23  7185805.44  30.90%  30.90%
    Asia    1999    Partners    2220718.23  7185805.44  30.90%  36.63%
    Europe  1999    Direct Sales    14265042.27 19508662.20 73.12%  66.70%
    Europe  1999    Direct Sales    14265042.27 19508662.20 73.12%  71.83%
    Europe  1999    Direct Sales    14265042.27 19508662.20 73.12%  73.12%
    Europe  1999    Internet    1533820.20  19508662.20 7.86%   6.16%
    Europe  1999    Internet    1533820.20  19508662.20 7.86%   7.86%
    Europe  1999    Internet    1533820.20  19508662.20 7.86%   9.66%
    Europe  1999    Partners    3709799.73  19508662.20 19.02%  18.32%
    Europe  1999    Partners    3709799.73  19508662.20 19.02%  19.02%
    Europe  1999    Partners    3709799.73  19508662.20 19.02%  27.14%
```

For Americas in the last column first 3 rows it's giving result for year 2000 then 1998, and then 1999, when in column before it's giving output for only year 1999 as needed.

Code that I used:

```
WITH previous_percentage AS(SELECT DISTINCT c3.region AS cr, t.year AS cy, c2.channel AS cd,
        TO_CHAR(sum(s.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY c2.channel, t.year, c3.region )
        /
        sum(s.amount_sold) OVER(PARTITION BY t.year, c3.region ) * 100, 'fm99D00%') AS previous_year
        FROM sh.sales s 
        JOIN sh.customers c ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id 
        JOIN sh.times t ON s.time_id = t.time_id 
        JOIN sh.channels c2 ON s.channel_id = c2.channel_id 
        JOIN sh.countries c3 ON c.country_id = c3.country_id 
        WHERE c3.region IN ('Americas', 'Europe','Asia') AND t.year IN ('1998','1999','2000')
        )   
SELECT DISTINCT c3.region, t.year, c2.channel,
sum(s.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY c2.channel, t.year, c3.region ) AS amount,
sum(s.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t.year, c3.region ) AS whole_sum,
TO_CHAR(sum(s.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY c2.channel, t.year, c3.country_region )
/
sum(s.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t.year, c3.region ) * 100, 'fm99D00%') AS percent_channels,
p.previous_year
FROM sh.sales s 
JOIN sh.customers c ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id 
JOIN sh.times t ON s.time_id = t.time_id 
JOIN sh.channels c2 ON s.channel_id = c2.channel_id 
JOIN sh.countries c3 ON c.country_id = c3.country_id 
JOIN previous_percentage p ON p.cr = c3.region AND p.cd = c2.channel 
WHERE c3.region IN ('Americas', 'Europe','Asia') AND t.year IN ('1999','2000','2001')
ORDER BY t.year ASC 
;
```

I tried to manipulate the query inside the CTE but couldn't get anything useful, I also thought that there is problems with dates which are different and I suspect that this is the main issue, but I don't know how to fix it. I suppose I made a mistake somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: Way too much data & way too much code & way too little investigation/debugging. [mre] "Minimal"--Don't just dump wrong code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions are your friend. Try this:

```sql
with t as
(
 select *, 
 lag(percentage) over (partition by area, department order by "year") as percentage_lag
 from the_table
)
select *, percentage - percentage_lag as percentage_dif
from t where percentage_lag is not null;
```

See more details in [DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t6pJyJyfPw3cRH428NmUjN/0).